# Do not make a double loop (While) as HasNext ()?

Tags: java, while-loop, distance

this code is double while loop ! but not double... only one loop > The end..
plz help me..
i want a double loop for while..
do not double loop for hasNext()?

---------------------------edit--------------

I'm sorry. I've made ​​a mistake Clumsy English. 
"Do not make a double loop (While) as HasNext ()?" What I'm asking. 
Sorry, I did not polite. 
Put the "While" he "HasNext ()" not been able to repeat the first loop. 
I'd like to create like multiplication like. Please help me.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.geotools.data.shapefile.files.ShpFiles;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileException;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader.Record;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;

class Point {

    double x;
    double y;

    Point(double x2, double y2) {
        this.x = x2;
        this.y = y2;
    }

    static double distance(Point p1, Point p2) {
        double dist;
        dist = Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y));
        return dist;
    }
}

public class KFunction {

    private static double X;
    private static double Y;
    private static double X1;
    private static double Y1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShapefileReader r = null;
        ShapefileReader r2 = null;
        try {
            ShpFiles shpFile = new ShpFiles("Juvenile_Offenders_in_Cardiff.shp");
            ShpFiles shpFile2 = new ShpFiles("Juvenile_Offenders_in_Cardiff.shp");

            GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
            r = new ShapefileReader(shpFile, true, false, geometryFactory);
            r2 = new ShapefileReader(shpFile2, true, false, geometryFactory);
            Record record2 = r2.nextRecord();
            Geometry shape2 = (Geometry) record2.shape();
            com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point centroid2 = shape2.getCentroid();
            int i = 0;
            boolean A = r2.hasNext();

            while (A) {
                X = centroid2.getX();
                Y = centroid2.getY();

                while (r.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("No." + i);

                    Record record = r.nextRecord();
                    Geometry shape = (Geometry) record.shape();
                    com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point centroid = shape.getCentroid();
                    X1 = centroid.getX();
                    Y1 = centroid.getY();

                    Point p1 = new Point(X, Y);
                    Point p2 = new Point(X1, Y1);

                    double result = Point.distance(p1, p2);

                    System.out.println("X : " + X + " Y : " + Y + " X1 : " + X1 + " Y1 : " + Y1);
                    System.out.println("두 점 사이의 거리 : " + result);
                    System.out.println("---------------------------");
                    i++;
                }
                break;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ShapefileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't cry in the title.

Comment: I'm crying right now

Comment: please clarify your question, 'i want a double loop' is so broad we cannot help you

Comment: You can't both not want *and* want something...well, you can but it's pointless. Do you want a double `while` or not, and if not what do you suppose should replace the offending one for a while?

Answer (score -1):

To me it looks like the outer loop while(A) would either be done not at all or forever since it appears the A never changes inside of it.